# generating unique random number javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get random unique number and assign it to variable .for example :

```
var nums=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
```

then i have 8 variables and i want to take one of these numbers, also to be unique, every time i refresh the page. I'm not very good at Javascript, so please help.

Comment: JavaScript can't help here. Only server-side can do what you want.

Comment: @VisioN There could be a new JavaScript API that enables this. I'm not sure, but I think I've come across something like that a while ago.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Well, TBH we can use localStorage and even cookies for that. But I'd go for server-side solution anyway.

Comment: You can do it from JS. Generate the random number `r = nums[Math.floor(Math.random() * 7)]` and append it to a cookie each time.

Comment: @techfoobar I don't think that `Math.random()` qualifies as truly random.

Comment: Yes, it is not and after a point patterns can probably be figured out. But it should be adequate in this case, since the OP will has to anyway ensure that it is not in the used set (keep generating till its not found in the cookie).

Comment: There is a coming API for cryptographically sound random numbers, but "random" and "unique" are not synonymous. If you mean "unique accross all users" then you need some server-side help. If you mean "unique in that session" JS can do this fine with cookies/localStorage.

Answer (score 2):

If the number only needs to be unique on the client side, it's possible.
You could create a number based off the current time for example:

```
var id = new Date().getTime();
```

However, if this unique ID needs to be unique for every client, as the comments in your OP state, you'll need a server-sided solution:

```
var id = "<?php echo uniqid() ?>";
```

Comment: thank you for answering,actually i expirimented and created this code var a = Math.floor(Math.random()*6);
var b =Math.floor(Math.random()*6);
var c=Math.floor(Math.random()*6);
var d=Math.floor(Math.random()*6);
var e=Math.floor(Math.random()*6);
var f=Math.floor(Math.random()*6);
and then i make a while and make comparision if some of the variable mathes to loop until it`s not matching and assign it to the variables again,but this is quite long and wrong code

Comment: If you execute this pro grammatically more than once in a row, you could get a collision .

Answer (score 1):

First off, to get a random value from the array, you could do this:

```
var nums = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * nums.length);

alert(num);
```

If you needed it to be unique, then it depends on what unique should mean. If you mean that for one user it should never repeat a number until they'd all been exhausted, then you could use a cookie to keep track of which had been shown.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function randomVarGenerator()
    {
    var s4=function()
    {
       return Math.floor(Math.random(0,9)*10).toString();

    };
    return (S4() + S4() + S4() + S4()  + S4() + S4()+ S4() + S4());
    }
randomVarGenerator();
```

if its generating uniqueString

```
 function randomVarGenerator()
    {
    var s4=function()
    {
       return Math.floor(Math.random() * 0x10000 /* 65536 */).toString(16);

    };
    return (S4() + S4() + S4() + S4()  + S4() + S4()+ S4() + S4());
    }
```

randomVarGenerator();

Comment: This does not guarantee uniqueness, and I don't think it is RFC compliant either. Just a simple way to get a guid-like number.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will be help to you. 
* First you should create an array that includes number.
* Then you should create another array 
* Then randomly pick a number from this array and place it to another
* After that remove the picked element from the number array.

```
function rand(n){

var numArr = new Array("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10");


var pickArr = new Array(); 

var length=16;

for(var i=0;i<n;i++){
        var num=numArr[Math.floor((Math.random()*length))];
        pickArr[pickArr.length]=num
        length--;
        numArr.splice(findRank(numArr,num), 1);

    }


    return pickArr;
}

function findRank(seq,n){
    var cnt=0;
    var flag=true;
    for(var i=0;i<seq.length&&flag;i++){
        if(seq[i]==n)flag=false;
        else cnt++;
    }

    return cnt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var n = 4, uniqueRandoms = [];
function makeUniqueRandom() {
    if (!uniqueRandoms.length) {
        for (var i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            uniqueRandoms.push(i); // generates [1,2,3,4]
        }
    }
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * uniqueRandoms.length),
        val = uniqueRandoms[index];
    uniqueRandoms.splice(index, 1);
    return val;
}

makeUniqueRandom(4); // use
```